# Class inside class for jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, transition

I want to fade-in my text using jquery. I've set everything up, but it doesn't seem to work. Perhaps someone can help me with this problem? This is what I have:

```
.nav ul li {
opacity: 0;
padding: 0px 50px;
transition: opacity 2s ease-in; 
/* and some more transitions for other browsers */
}

.nav ul li.fade {
opacity: 1;
/* The problem is probably here: class inside of another class */
}
```

jquery:

```
$('ul.nav li').addClass('fade');
```

I hope someone can help me out. I do not know to fix this problem. I've looked up for some solutions, but I do not think they fix my problem. Thanks in advance.
Edit: I got this from an example from this website and was going to try it out.

Edit 2:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J6PC9/):

```
<title>title</title>
<body>
<div id='container'>
        <div id='navLeft' class='nav'>
        <ul>
        <li>link1</li>
        <li>link2</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div id='logo'>
        <img src='images/logo.png' alt='logo' />
        </div>
        <div id='navRight' class='nav'>
        <ul>
        <li>link3</li>
        <li>link4</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
```

My  tags:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/class.js"></script>
```

Comment: Post your markup/a jsFiddle example showing the problem please..

Comment: what does your html look like?

Comment: why don't you just use `fadeIn()` instead of adding a class...

Comment: Bipen, I actually was going to change the fade-in to a more complicated animation, but used the fade to start of with. Thanks for reminding me, though!

Comment: working fiddle `-->`http://jsfiddle.net/2cpX6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your jsFiddle, you need to use:

```
$('div.nav ul li').addClass('fade');
```

and change your CSS to:

```
div.nav ul li.fade {
    opacity: 1; 
}
```

Because in your HTML, it is the `<div>` that has the class `.nav`:

```
<div id='navRight' class='nav'>
```

[**Here's the jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/J6PC9/1/)

Comment: It seems to work in jsFiddle, thanks for that. But for some reason it doesn't work with my own website. Can this be a problem with the link to jquery? I got it from google's library.

Comment: @Blooded Are you getting any errors in the console? It should work if that's what your HTML actually looks like. Does any jQuery work?

Comment: It is the actual code. I do not know how to test whether jquery is working or not easily; this actually was my test to set up jquery, haha. This is what I have at the bottom of my page, before the body tag closes: (I will add it at my post at the top of the page, makes it easier to read!)

Comment: @Blooded What does it say in your Console though? If you open up Chrome tools or Firebug you will get an error if there's a problem

Comment: Hmm, I do get this:
Failed to load resource file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @Blooded You're calling jQuery before it's been loaded. Put the two scripts before you use any javascript/jQuery, e.g. the head or right at the top of the body :)

Comment: Put it in the header, but still get the same error. This seems to be a long doctor examination...

Comment: @Blooded Place your code inside a $(document).ready(function(){  }); after you have loaded the scripts, place your scripts in the top of the body. If it doesn't work after that, send me a pastebin link to your whole page.

Comment: You want the html, css and jquery all in one file?

Comment: @Blooded I want them exactly how you have them, if separate that's fine

Comment: @Blooded Just use this instead: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Wow, all that for just such a simple answer. Thank you though - it is finally fixed after one hour! Thanks for your help, much appreciated. You have a nice amount of knowledge in programming, I am jealous. :p

Comment: @Blooded Yeah, I just needed to see for myself why it was reading //ajax.google as an interal file instead of linking to the website like it should :s anyway, don't worry, once you get into jQuery you will learn fast and be a pro in no time :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this:

```
ul.nav li.fade {
```

instead of this?

```
.nav ul li.fade {
```

Also change the first ".nav ul" to "ul.nav"

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
$('.nav ul li').addClass('fade');
```

since `.nav ul li` is the selector with the transition property on it

Comment: I tried that at first, but didn't work. I looked it up and another post told me that 'ul.nav li' was the way to go. It could be wrong, though, I am still new. ;)

Comment: @Blooded Your selector in the css window is `nav ul li` in the fiddle when it should be `.nav ul li`, notice the dot.

Comment: I almost got it working, I accidentally removed the dot. You are right with your answer, I got it wrong, but for some reason my jquery doesn't load properly. Thanks for your help.